# NGINX - Redirecting from non www to wwww

Tags: nginx, https, no-www

I registered a domain mydomain.it and a CNAME www.mydomain.it.

- the DNS for mydomain.it is my server 123.123.123.123
- the CNAME for www.mydomain.it is mydomain.it

**The problem is:** when I write https://mydomain.it/app the NGINX does not redirect me to https://www.mydomain/app, but renders https://mydomain.it/app and I cannot see the images and have some problems with CORS.

On my server I configured NGINX as follows:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.mydomain.it  mydomain.it;
    return      301 https://www.mydomain.it$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    server_name mydomain.it;
    ssl_certificate ........
    ssl_certificate_key ...........
    return      301 https://www.mydomain.it$request_uri;
}

server {
      listen      443 http2 ssl;
      listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;      
      server_name  www.mydomain.it;
      ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin mydomain.it;      
      ssl_certificate .........
      ssl_certificate_key .........


      location /app/ {
          proxy_set_header HOST $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:6001/;
          proxy_connect_timeout 600;
          proxy_send_timeout 600;
          proxy_read_timeout 600;
          send_timeout 600;
      }

      location / {
        root /var/www/prod;
      }

      # gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/ja$;
}
```

Is the configuration correct?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the full configuration that Nginx is using. Check your `server_name` directives. Did you restart Nginx and clear your browser's cache?

Comment: of course i restarted NGINX, i creared the cache and the problem still appears